# Unindexed field of Objectify entity has index in GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

[Objectify documentation](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#defining-indexes) says that Objectify will not create an index for a field which is not annotated with `@Index` annotation. However, I can see that index is being create for entity fields which are arrays, or maps.

I'm using Objectify v6.0.4 to store data in GAE Datastore.
I tried putting `@Unindex` annotation to the filed I don't want to index, but it didn't worked.

For example, when I save tho following entity and check it in Datastore I see that index has been created for `fields`.

```java
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  public Field[] fields;
}

static class Field {
  public String type;
  public String label;
  public String name;
}
```

Based on Objectify documentation I'm expecting that datastore index will be created for the fields with `@Index` annotation only.
Is it Objectify issue, or GAE Datastore issue?

Comment: What makes you think an index has been created for `fields` - and what would that mean, since indexes are only created on leaf nodes (`type`, `label`, `name`)?

Comment: In GAE Datastore dashboard for the entity I see that index size for ``fields`` is not ``0B`` and keeps growing as I add new entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more details about this issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2615). In Datastore the field types of array are always showing indexed regardless of excludeFromIndexes parameter value.

It is not known if this is an issue, or intended behaviour, but it looks like this can be an inconsistency between the google-cloud-node library and the API.